# Is this HSTS HTTP Response Header Misconfigured?

Tags: web-application, http, webserver, web, hsts

I recently discovered during a penetration test that the HSTS was returned by the application but in this format:

**"Strict-TransportSecurity"**

Instead of:

**"Strict-Transport-Security"**

Does this format mean that the header (HSTS) is not validated by the client and prevented from doing what it is designed to do? As I understand HTTP headers are case insensitive but I'm not sure if this is a valid header name.

Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## This is an undefined header.

As such, how browsers react to it is browser-dependent. It is *possible*, but very unlikely, that they will still interpret the header correctly. However, I would not bet on it.

Instead, change the header from `Strict-TransportSecurity` to `Strict-Transport-Security`.